# Are SharePoint versioning possible to validate according to Food Safety Standards?

Tags: document-library, versioning, validation

Use Case: I often tell future customers that “Sure, you will have previous versions available for those with the right permissions”. While that is true, I wonder if I can get away with that statement meeting a Quality Manager of any Food Industry concerned of [Food Safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food_safety). She (or he) will immediately ask the one question I fear the most: *“Nice, but is it valid according to [ISO 22 000](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_22000), [BRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Retail_Consortium) and [FDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food_and_Drug_Administration) regulations?”*

I will not know what to answer. I know that there have been made attempts to do so in [Life Science](http://www.slideshare.net/Montrium/validating-sharepoint-for-regulated-life-sciences-applications), but I’m not sure it’s enough or if it’s even tested in the food industry. Where can I find scientific proof that SharePoint versioning handling is valid according to Food Safety Standards in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharepoint 2007 and earlier are not (AFAIK) validate-able. Sharepoint 2010 and up are (AFAIK). However! This will require that your systems are [Part 11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_21_CFR_Part_11) compliant. Being Part 11 compliant means not needing hard copies of everything for regulations. It's pretty costly to validate your system, since you have to take lots of measures to prevent false data being entered, including user logins.

Here's Microsoft's whitepaper on the topic: [Whitepaper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CEIQFjAA&url=http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/A/A/9AA9CACF-B414-466B-BBED-86507D1D24FF/SharePoint-Configuration-Guidance-for-21-CFR-Part-11-Compliance.pdf&ei=5UGdUuSnMpLroASg_YCQBQ&usg=AFQjCNH2gNYCWINf16YQi_5rncblw4hZHg&bvm=bv.57155469,d.cGU)